# Make local urllib settings local?

Tags: python, urllib

I have a multi-threaded process. And for each thread, the following code is ran; however, it overwrites the proxy used for each thread to the latest proxy added. Is there a way I can make this proxy-settings local to the thread?

```
        self.p_handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http' : self.proxy})
        self.opener = urllib.request.build_opener(self.p_handler)
        urllib.request.install_opener(self.opener)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `install_opener` (which installs it globally), just call the `open` method of your `opener` object, and then transfer the results into a file.

```
self.p_handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http' : self.proxy})
self.opener = urllib.request.build_opener(self.p_handler)
result = self.opener.open(url)
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: result.read(1024), ''):
        f.write(chunk)
```

The last 2 lines here are just to avoid having to hold the entire file in memory; they allow it to stream through in kilobyte-sized chunks. If you don't mind having it in memory, the last bit gets simpler:

```
result = self.opener.open(url)
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result.read())
```

Comment: Ah, didn't see I could do that directly. Thank you. :)

Comment: Oh, right, forgot that `urlretrieve` was deprecated. I think the preferred way to do this now is to use `open()` and read the contents from it, writing them into a file. If you really don't want to do that, however, you can create your own `URLopener` object: http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.URLopener